# How to work around "React Hook "useTable" is called conditionally|

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on `react-table` library to make table order by columns. To do that I am going through `react-table` documentation. When I modified my react table component I started getting this error:

```
React Hook "useTable" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same 
order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?  
react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

I tried multiple approaches from previous threads on properly using react hooks but became unsuccessful.

Here is my code for the table component and where I am getting the error:

```
const WidgetTable = ({ title, data, href, width }) => {
    if (data.type === 'loading') {
        return <WidgetBase title={title} loading={true} />;
    }

    if (data.type === 'empty') {
        return <WidgetBase title={title} noData={true} href={href} />;
    }

    if (data.type === 'error') {
        return <WidgetBase title={title} error={true} href={href} />;
    }

    let { rows, columns } = data;

    const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = useTable({ rows, columns });

    if (width === 1) {
        return (
            <WidgetBase title={title} href={href}>
                <WidgetTableCardBox rows={rows} columns={columns} />
            </WidgetBase>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <WidgetBase title={title} href={href}>
                <table {...getTableProps} width={width} height={height} onS>
                    <thead>
                        <tr {...headerGroups.getTableBodyProps()}>
                            {headerGroups.headers.map(column => (
                                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()} key={column.rawName} width={width} height={height}>
                                    {column.render('Header')}
                                </th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                        {rows.map(row => {
                            prepareRow(row);
                            return (
                                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                                    {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                        return (
                                            <td
                                                {...cell.getCellProps()}
                                                // key={column.rawName}
                                                width={width}
                                                height={height}
                                                // title={row[column.rawName].value}
                                            >
                                                {cell.render('Cell')}
                                            </td>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </WidgetBase>
        );
    }
};

export default WidgetTable;
```

AS per the [Rule of Hookes](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), As stated there in the rules hooks must be placed on top of the component before any return statement. I tried shifting this line of code above all the `if` statements:

```
let { rows, columns } = data;
const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = useTable({ rows, columns });
```

But did not work.

What would be the optimal solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to skip the last `else` part and just return JSX. And also move `useTable()` to the top

```js
const WidgetTable = ({ title, data, href, width }) => {
  let { rows, columns, type } = data;

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({ rows, columns });

  if (type === "loading") {
    return <WidgetBase title={title} loading={true} />;
  }

  if (type === "empty") {
    return <WidgetBase title={title} noData={true} href={href} />;
  }

  if (type === "error") {
    return <WidgetBase title={title} error={true} href={href} />;
  }

  if (width === 1) {
    return (
      <WidgetBase title={title} href={href}>
        <WidgetTableCardBox rows={rows} columns={columns} />
      </WidgetBase>
    );
  }

  return (
    <WidgetBase title={title} href={href}>
      <table {...getTableProps} width={width} height={height} onS>
        <thead>
          <tr {...headerGroups.getTableBodyProps()}>
            {headerGroups.headers.map(column => (
              <th
                {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                key={column.rawName}
                width={width}
                height={height}
              >
                {column.render("Header")}
              </th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map(row => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return (
                    <td
                      {...cell.getCellProps()}
                      // key={column.rawName}
                      width={width}
                      height={height}
                      // title={row[column.rawName].value}
                    >
                      {cell.render("Cell")}
                    </td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </WidgetBase>
  );
};

export default WidgetTable;
```

Comment: I did move the `const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = useTable({ tableRows, columns });` on top and skipped `else` part.

I am getting this error on console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')` at `useTable` line. Any Idea why is that?

Comment: Wherever you are using map you could check if `array.length` is greater than 0.
Like here `headerGroups.headers && headerGroups.headers.length > 0 && headerGroups.headers.map`

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I did some analysis after using `array.length` check but seems like it is also not working. Though, in analysis, I found out that my `data` for `WidgetTable` is only available completely and populated after `data.type === 'success' ` is `true`. No matter what and how I put checks on my `data` I am still getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') at useTable`.

Comment: My guess is on this issue is to separate out all the `data.type` checks in a custom hook and wait for the `data` to be completely loaded for `useTable` hook. What are your thoughts on this? will it be possible, if yes how can I implement this?

Comment: Could you reproduce your example in a sandbox?

Comment: Hi, So I worked this issue out. I created a separate function before this`WidgetTable` component gets its data and renders. In that function using `if` statements I am waiting for the data to completely loaded and then passing that data using `props` to `WidgetTable` component. Thanks for showing me the right way to resolve this error.